# Finding a good design pattern for Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to develop a application which process multiple version of same form (XML). The part that I need help is when the application is trying to convert xml into jaxb object to process and persist into database. I thought about using factory design pattern to provide form processor for each version of the form. However, since the application has a requirement to maintain all previous form version, if-else (or switch) can get really long in the factory class. Is there other cleaner and better design pattern other than factory design?

Comment: Consider adding your code to the question

Comment: It is still in design phase, so there is no sample code that I can include.

Answer (score 0):

If you have different sets of fields in different versions and want to create a class to proceed them all, you should take a look at Builder design pattern.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#Java